# Copying a timestamped file, renaming it and changing contents on the fly

Tags: javascript, bash, sequelize-cli

I had about 30 migration files (sequelize) looking like the following that I wanted to copy into migrations for another table, while changing the migration file's name (sequelize relies on utc-timestamp) and changing the table-name in the file at the same time:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.addColumn("Providers", "column-name", { type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(8, 2) });
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.removeColumn("Providers", "column-name");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in migrations/*[ce]c-to*; do cat "$f" | sed 's/Providers/PracticeAssignments/g' > migrations/$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S' -u)-$(echo $f | sed 's/provider/practice-assignment/g' | cut -d'-' -f2-); done
```

^^that script seemed to have done the trick!